# Python Django App Design change on deploy to server

Tags: python, css, django

I recently uploaded my Django App to the server (Digital Ocean). The functionality is okay as in my local project on my computer, but the design (css style) of the Admin Interface has changed drastically in a lot of elements of the change_list and change_form templates. I‘ve checked and made sure that the templates of my local Django and Suit files are the same as they of the server, but it is still not the same design.

Does anyone has experience with that?

Comment: What do you mean drastically changed? Did you check the developer console to see if you're even receiving your static files properly. If you have set `DEBUG` to `False`, then Django doesn't serve static files.

Comment: Did you configure asset, static folder by using concept of [python manage.py collectstatic](https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files#toc-collecting-static-files)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, although the static files are already in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In deployment server just collect your static files from static folder by running command python manage.py collectstatic which will create a staticfiles folder in your Main project app in the project directory. May be this will help. Try it out.